# Difference between single and double quotes in subprocess [Python 3.4]

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm using Python 3.4 in Windows Server 12 and I have some Python code that executes the ffmpeg command bellow:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n\,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)' -c:v rawvideo  -pix_fmt uyvy422 -y output.avi`

I use the following code to execute the external command:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print ("Command %s failed with error code" % command, exc.returncode, exc.output, file=sys.stderr)
```

When I pass the command enclosed in single quotes it successfully runs the command:

`command = 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select="not(mod(n\,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)" -c:v rawvideo  -pix_fmt uyvy422 -y output.avi'`

When I pass the command as a string enclosed in double quotes it fails:

`command = "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n\,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)' -c:v rawvideo  -pix_fmt uyvy422 -y output.avi"`

The error message is the following:

```
[Eval @ 0000000eaf2fe040] Invalid chars ',setpts=N/((30)*TB)' at the end of expression 'not(mod(n,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)'  
[Parsed_select_0 @ 0000000eb0d27ca0] Error while parsing expression 'not(mod
(n,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)'  
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000eb0d0a5a0] Error initializing filter 'select' with args 'not(mod(n\\,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)'  
Error opening filters!"
```

So it appears that when using double quotes the slash `/` that is part of the `setpts=N/((30)*TB)` option is not interpreted correctly, while with double quotes there's no problem. Note that both commands (either with double or single quotes in the select option) work fine when I run them directly from the command prompt. 
However, I've seen many people saying that from a technical perspective single and double quotes make no difference, e.g.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155176/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155176/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes

Does slash parsing depend on the quotes around the string or this is just a behavior specific to the executable I'm running?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I'm having the same problem with Python 3.5.0 in Blender.
When I write:

```
addr_cal.append(addr + "calibration")
sock_cal.connect(addr_cal[0])
```

It does not work (Errno 11, Connection Refused), but with:

```
addr_cal.append(addr + 'calibration')
```

It works perfect. Everywhere on the Internet people say that it's only a style matter, but clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose problem is not in Python, but somewhere in subprocess or lower... Doublequotes have command line meaning - they allow send a space or non-letter char in argument. Maybe a singlequote inside string makes it fail?

Try
`command = "ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select=\"not(mod(n\,30)),setpts=N/((30)*TB)\" -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt uyvy422 -y output.avi"`

(`\"` instead of `'` inside a string)